# Changing DataTemplate with Property Binding in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, datatemplate, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to implement this using Eugene Akinshin's code from here: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/237947.aspx/1

It seems like a really nice way to bind to already-existing properties and means the configuration can all be defined in XAML.

*However*, I can't get it to work.

I'm defining the templates to use like this:

```
<Converters:TemplateSelectorConverter x:Key="templateConverter">
    <Converters:TemplateSelectorCase TemplateReference="Minimised" Template="{StaticResource SmallOrders}"/>
    <Converters:TemplateSelectorCase TemplateReference="Restored" Template="{StaticResource MediumOrders}"/>
    <Converters:TemplateSelectorCase TemplateReference="Maximised" Template="{StaticResource LargeOrders}"/>
</Converters:TemplateSelectorConverter>
```

and then setting the item template of my `ListBox` like this:

```
ItemTemplate="{Binding CurrentState, Converter={StaticResource templateConverter}}"
```

`CurrentState` is a string of either 'Minimised', 'Maximised' or 'Restored' (I've edited the linked example to have a string as the key rather than an int) and is set to 'Minimised' by default, but all I get is a list of **`Cannot create [my object type]`** in my `ListBox`.

The templates definitely work as I can expose the View in the ViewModel and set the DataTemplate in code, and there are visual states that rely on the same `CurrentState` property which work, so I know the View can access the property correctly. Unfortunately, if I breakpoint the `Convert()` method in the converter, it never gets hit.

All suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have figured this out or not but placement of the Converter definition in the Resource in relationship to the DataTemplate will be the difference between it working and not working.

The Converter needs to be placed prior to the Data Template.